# I'm travelling to the UK to study and I must continue a vaccine treatment, how do I do it?

Tags: uk, europe, health, study

I get a vaccine shot every month, and I get to store the doses in my fridge. However now at the end of September I am travelling to the UK to study there. I am from Spain and I was told by my doctor that people have previously done it and translated all the required documents to English.

However I don't know who I should contact there and how to arrange it. I also don't know how I would take the vaccines with me because they must be in the fridge at all times. They can be out of the fridge for like an hour / hour and a half. No more. And the trip from here to when I reach my destination and get to a fridge will be a lot of hours. What can I do?

Comment: Ugh, this question is completely relevant to either Travel or Expats. Why don't I edit out the "to study there" phrase which should make it on topic for Travel? I've traveled on a holiday where I had to transport the 2nd dose of a vaccine that required refrigeration. Possible duplicate [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34618/where-is-the-best-place-to-carry-perishable-foods-on-long-international-flights/34621#34621) also.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think you should translate all the relevant medical documentation into English, find your local GP in the UK and talk to them. Regarding transportation of the medicines, I did it before: I used a good thermal flask (e.g. Thermos) filled with ice to keep the temperature low. It did work reasonably well for a few hours.

A hardcore option (which I actually did before): learn how to administer the vaccine yourself (or teach someone who will be around) and just do it yourself. Obviously this is not recommended in countries with good healthcare system like the UK.

Comment: Thanks, isn't there a way to transport luggage that needs special care like being at a certain temperature? I'll try asking my airline, but I have no idea to be frank.